# EJB: @remote, @local and @localbean, it's correct to expose all of them?

Tags: jakarta-ee, interface, ejb

I'm wondering if I'm messing up all my code or if my solution is acceptable: I have a EJB, let's call it Customer. Customer is used by other EJBs, by a primefaces page (in the same JVM) and by a servlet (maybe in the same JVM, maybe not).
So I've coded this:

```
// this is in RemoteIntefaces.jar
@Remote
public interface CustomerRemote {
  public methodA();
}

// this is in LocalInterfaces.jar
@Local
public interface CustomerLocal {
  public methodB();
}

// this is in the EJB project
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Customer implements CustomerRemote, CustomerLocal {
  @Override
  public methodA() {
    [...]
  }
  @Override
  public methodB() {
    [...]
  }
  public methodC() {
    [...}
  }
}
```

methodA is called remotely, from the servlet, using RemoteInterfaces.jar:

```
@EJB
private CustomerRemote customer;
[...]
public myFunction() {
  customer.methodA();
}
```

methodB is called from a primefaces baking bean, using LocalInterfaces.jar:

```
@EJB
private CustomerLocal customer;
[...]
public myFunction() {
  customer.methodB();
}
```

methodC is used by another EJB in the same EJB project:

```
@EJB
private Customer customer;
[...]
public myFunction() {
  customer.methodC();
}
```

I don't want methodC being exposed to the external interfaces, and so I decided not to put it in any interface

is't working fine, but I don't know if it's correct or if it's a bad practice or if it have some negative side effect. 
It's not about "I think its good", I've already have an opinion, the point is if exists any documentation about "implementing all possible views" :P

Thank you | Gracias | Grazie

Answer (score 0):

> the point is if exists any documentation about "implementing all possible views"

The ejb-3.1 [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/) provides some guidelines about this topic.

> Chapter 3 Client View of a Session Bean
>
> ...
>   The client of a session bean may be a local client, a remote client, or a web service client, depending on
>   which of **these views is provided by the bean** and used by the client.
>
> **While it is possible to provide more than one client view for a session bean, typically only one will be
>   provided.**...

Comment: yes, "tipically", but in real life code I see that's a lot more "typical" to have beans with two views. Personally I think it's ok, it's normal to have to access your "customer" logic from ui and internally (I'm thinking for example about customer.load(idCustomer)...)

Comment: According to my experience, I agree that typically a bean exposes only one client view, but probably it depends on each project requirements.

Comment: I've read somewhere that annotate a bean with Local and Remote is an anti-pattern, but it's ok if a bean implement two different interface, one annotated with Local and one with Remote.
I've to admin that I'm a little confused about what is an anti-pattern or not regarding bean views...

Comment: takes a look at this [article](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/beans_with_both_views_local)

Comment: Thank you for the link gabriel, I knew it, but it's pretty "old" (2009), so I don't know if it's still valid and it say nothing about having Local, Remote and LocalBean. 
Anyway this article let me think about *how* to do it in a good way, with common interface and base classes...